# How to delete white area between content and popover arrow ios

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, popover

I set the content and the size of popover exactly I needed. However, there is a white area between my content (even though I have set up constraints to every sides in distance 0) and the arrow of popover window. How can I delete this white area or change its color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out this white area was the navigation bar of this view controller. I didn't know navigation bars appear when we present view controller as a popover. So, the solution is as simply as follows:

**Swift 3:**

```
nav.isNavigationBarHidden = true //simply hide the navigation bar
```

For a full example of usage:

```
//instantiation of your VC may be different
let popoverContent: BackgroundColorPaletteViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController() 
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: popoverContent)
nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
let popover = nav.popoverPresentationController
popoverContent.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 40)
popover?.delegate = self
popover?.sourceView = sender
popover?.sourceRect = sender.bounds
nav.isNavigationBarHidden = true //simply hide the navigation bar

self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```